# Am I the only one really annoyed by the new chat feature

Tags: discussion, user-interface

where the site keeps asking me if I want to chat with an expert? Maybe there should be something between being bothered every few minutes and never seeing it again.

Comment: There is a "Never" link you can click. Additionally, it's a joke that will be gone by tomorrow. Addtional information can be found on META

Comment: @jim the never doesn't work :(

Comment: A very unfunny April Fools joke

Comment: I see no "never" link.

Comment: One thing I've learned is that you can't outsmart the expert in a battle of wits. You'll lose! :D

Comment: Well root my boot, it never even entered my head that it might be an April Fool's joke. I just assumed it was a link to the chat functionality, clicked "never", and never gave it any more thought.

Comment: @Jim "Addtional information can be found on META"??? This _is_ META ;) Forget about MSO, if you can answer this question here, please do. The Workplace community should feel confident that they'll find all their Meta answers here, there's no need for any Workplace user to go scouting MSO for answers...

Comment: @Yannis very true. I was on my phone, so linking to/copying text from MSO to here would be a hassle (hence the comment instead of an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an April Fools joke, and now it's gone.

Some people liked it, some people didn't. A *lot* of people thought it was an actual feature.

Comment: I know that it got frustrated with me when our conversation went off on a tangent because it said: "So have you given up on asking a question about slapping your bosses wife?"